# How to commit mutation from `plugins` directory using Nuxt.js?

Tags: vue.js, nuxt.js

I have just run into such a problem, I am trying to customize Axios module, My aim is to access my `dom.js` vuex module state from 'plugins' directory, The code below works but I have the following error in the console

> Do not mutate vuex store state outside mutation handlers

So, The reason for this error is also clear to me, I wonder how I can Commit mutation from 'plugins' directory to my `dom.js` vuex module?
Thanks!

```js
//plugins/axios.js
export default function ({ $axios, redirect, store}) {
    $axios.onError(error => {
      const code = parseInt(error.response && error.response.status)
      if (code === 401) {
         store.state.dom.alertIs = true
        redirect('/')
      }
    })
  }
```

```js
/store/dom.js
export const state = () => ({
    alertIs:false
})
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Declare a [mutation](https://vuex.vuejs.org/guide/mutations.html) (named `"SET_DOM_ALERT"`) in your store:

```js
// store/dom.js
export default {
  state: () => ({
    alertIs: false
  }),
  mutations: {
    SET_DOM_ALERT(state, value) {
      state.alertIs = value
    }
  }
}
```

Then, use [`store.commit('dom/SET_DOM_ALERT', newValue)`](https://vuex.vuejs.org/api/#commit) in your plugin (notice the `dom/` prefix for the namespace):

```js
// plugins/axios.js
export default function ({ $axios, redirect, store}) {
  $axios.onError(error => {
    const code = parseInt(error.response && error.response.status)
    if (code === 401) {
      store.commit('dom/SET_DOM_ALERT', true) // 
      redirect('/')
    }
  })
}
```

[demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/nuxt-store-mutation-from-plugin?file=store%2Findex.js)